# php xml большие связанные файлы как лучше обработать

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser, solr

Есть 3 связанных xml файла, тоесть id из первого есть в других.
файлы размером от 100мб до 2-3 гб. Кому интересно это база адресов ГАР.

1й файл названия объектов
2й файл характеристики
3й иерархия - какой объект за каким идет. Родители объектов

вопрос как мне это лучше связать и обработать?

Единичный файл я обрабатываю php XMLReader - он не грузит файл в память. А идет по нему от начала до конца. постепенно. НО мне надо как то связать данные. из первого взять имя объета. из второго параметры. А из 3го взять кто родитель. И все это записать в solr.
Солр на сколько я знаю не умеет обновлять данные запросом. Надо сначала снова получить документы. переписать в них поля и снова добавить.

каждый раз доставать и сохранять это в солр это как то медленно.

Я сначала сделал добавление всех данных в базу mysql в 3 таблицы. Потом делаю запрос на связывание этих данных и уже это добавляю в solr постепенно пачками по 1000 документов.

Вроде работает но все равно как то медленно.
Там на хабре ребята хвастались что несколько часов всю базу обрабатывают. У меня только минут 20-50 уходит на обработку 1 региона. Их там 99.

Вообщем может есть какой то интересный способ как связывать данные в больших xml чтоб без промежуточной базы.

Comment: С ходу только такая идея:Сначала проиндексировать документы и запомнить какой объект в каком месте документа хранится. И при обработке обращаться уже по конкретному местонахождению объекта с конкретным смещением.

Comment: Ну и с вашей стороны было бы неплохо посчитать сколько и на что уходит времени, а потом уже править. Ибо вы можете и ошибаться в узком месте. Было бы неплохо знать наверняка сколько на что уходит. Рискуете быть неприятно удивлены после переписи всего с нуля.

Comment: отказался от mysql  и нашел все же solr можно обновлять документ. поэтому обрабатываю xml файлы по очереди и отправляю в солр пачками по 5000 шт,  скорость возрасла. но все равно не пару часов. где то 20 минут на 1 гб данных. А там их 57 гб полезных данных. Итого примерно 19 часов.

Comment: Ну, а вы сравнивали производительность и ресурсы вашей машины с производительностью и ресурсами машины, используемой в статье на хабре? Плюм про тюнинг и настройку не стоит забывать и как и про другие части вашего алгоритма.

Comment: Собственно, о чем я и писал выше...
было бы неплохо сначала замеры сделать, а потом уже это исправлять

Comment: Также не стоит забывать о том, какие технологии использовали вы, а какие технологии использовали в статье на хабре... Там могли на C# параллельно в несколько десятков потоков все расхлебать, в то время как вы на php в один долбитесь